# How can I calculate the distance based on type of transportation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How can use google map API to calculate the distance between two places based on type of transportation?

I need to design something like the google map itself, set the origin and destination then set the transportation type (car, walking, public transporation) then it calculate the distance based on them.

My application is a web application not a mobile application.

Comment: Where to display it ? on android or what

Comment: for now i can find the coordination of origin and distance but nothing have been found for distance calculation based on trasportation

Comment: @EmeEmertana Does distance use on any purpose or only for visual only??

Comment: I just want to show the time that it takes from origin to destination with each type of transportation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Distance Matrix to solve the issue, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate distance between two geo-coordinate then you can use **hypersion formula**.It give the same distance between two point. If you want to calculate the distance based on the transportation, I think you have to do it yourself manually.

```
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  return d.toFixed(3);
}
```

EDITED:To display the path based on different mean of transportation you can call url like below.I don't know where it is correct way to do or not.

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLatitude+","+currentLongitude+"&daddr="+fixedLatitude+","+fixedLongitude;
```

Comment: @EmeEmertana I think difference distance based on the transportation between source and destination can't be calculated...When I calculate the distance between two geo-coordinate using `hypersion formula` and match the distance display on google map ,Both are same... But if you have fixed location to show distance(fixed route) then you can do it manually by taking different intermediate geo-coordinate for different mean of transportation and finally add the intermediate distance to find total...

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "Direction"

have a look at this part of doc:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes

Take care, you have [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits)

Comment: you are right I can amend it to my purpose, but is it possible to give a street address not just cities ?

Comment: I've not used that stuff, but it seems you can put a full street adress into params named 'origin' and destination' of the request.